# Cordova: Android target: not installed avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to work with cordova and after installing android studio, SDK and all other requirements when I check the requirements I get the following error:

[image]

all solutions I found here say I should add Both JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME to environment variables, also the path of tools, tools/bin and platform-tools, which I did:
 [image]
and still the same error.. I dont know what to do :(

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I needed to also set java home in /etc/environment as follows:
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

and now the problem is solved:)